# Location of the local copy of Docker's registry manifest-file

Tags: docker

Looks like a Docker image has two manifests. One is local, that is saved as a part of `docker save`, for example, and a different one that is generated when the image is being pushed to Docker registry.

So, my question is there a way to find this [*registry* manifest file](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/#image-manifest)? Is it stored somewhere locally? Maybe inside the `Docker.qcow2` image?

Comment: what is this needed for ?

Comment: Automation of some sort. Why does it matter?

Comment: Just trying to understand use case so if something else comes to my mind then i can suggest that

Comment: I need to parse it and upload it to a URL.

Comment: Since you mentioned `qcow2` I assume you are using Docker for mac. You can use the command `docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh` to get a shell inside the main machine. `cat /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/repositories.json` will give you all the images.  And `cat /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/a20fd0d59cf13f82535ccdda818d70b97ab043856e37a17029e32fc2252b8c56` will print the layers of debian image. See if these pointers are of any help? I am still not 100% sure on your query

Comment: [Here's a manifest of an image in a registry](https://jbaruch.jfrog.io/jbaruch/docker/couchbase-javaee/latest/manifest.json). It was uploaded from my machine when I ran `docker push`. Is there a way to find it locally on my machine?

Comment: Seems like this is generated at runtime https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/cb952bf00695b3429476f59c5534a9c604c6f010/distribution/metadata/v2_metadata_service.go

Comment: Thanks, @TarunLalwani. That's a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today's Docker engine uses the manifest as a guide to determine what other content (layer blobs) to download during a `docker run` where the image is not local or `docker pull`. However, it does not store the manifest as JSON in a local cache that I'm aware of, leaving you without an easy spot to go get the actual registry's manifest.

Two things that may be of interest:

1. We are in the process of [adding a new `docker manifest` command](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/138) for direct interaction with the manifest object that may be of interest to what you are trying to do.
2. This is mostly to support the "manifest list" v2.2 spec type that supports multi-platform images, based on the [`manifest-tool` work](https://github.com/estesp/manifest-tool) I did originally to create and query manifests from a registry.

However, if those two bits of code/projects aren't directly useful, you may be able to hack one or both of them to just dump a registry manifest JSON object pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks, @phil-e. Looks like I'll have to download it back again right after `pull`. Feeling pretty stupid doing it, though.